# Jetpack Profileinstaller bundled into release APK

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

After receiving a crash triggered in class androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243851384) I was wondering what caused the dependency androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller to appear in my release APK, and found it to be a dependency of androidx.compose.ui:ui 1.3.0.
Is there a specific reason for compose.ui:ui package to require androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller in a release build?

Answer (score 3):

I found the explanation here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/ergonomics#profile-inst

> Jetpack Compose 1.0 utilizes profile installation for release builds. Profile installers allow apps to specify critical code to be AOT compiled at installation time.